# JSHint - allow variable reassigment

Tags: jshint

The following causes JSHint to say `'path' is already defined`. This seems valid as I am just reassigning the variable to itself.

```
for(var i = 0, path = path.split('.'), len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
  if(!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') return def;
  obj = obj[path[i]];
}
```

Id like to keep the setting I have for the real already defined cases and the above works great. Suggestions as to make jshint shut up on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably already know, `var i = 0, path = path.split('.'), len = path.length;` is equivalent to `var i = 0; var path = path.split('.'); var len = path.length;` which is why JSHint complains about redefining an existing variable.

The obvious solution (and, many would argue, "best practice") is to not reuse the variable.

```
for(var i = 0, parts = path.split('.'), len = parts.length; i < len; i++) {
  if(!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') return def;
  obj = obj[parts[i]];
}
```

The other solution is to put the variable reassignment outside the loop. It doesn't change anything in how the script works, other than now it doesn't try to redeclare the variable.

```
path = path.split('.');

for(var i = 0, len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
  if(!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') return def;
  obj = obj[path[i]];
}
```

Comment: The first option you have causes the same path not defined warning. The second one works thanks.